# Excel XLS vlookup return multiple values in same cell based on multiple corresponding lookups

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I use `vlookup` often to return a single value based on a single lookup. But I have a case where I have multiple values in a cell separated by commas, and need to return a lookup of corresponding values, also comma separated.

My lookup cells would look like this:

| Color | Key |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Yellow | 3 |
| Green | 4 |

Here is what I need in the output (the Keys (joined) column)

| Color(s) | Keys (joined) |
| --- | --- |
| Red, Yellow | 1, 3 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Blue, Green | 2, 4 |
| Yellow, Blue, Red | 3,2,1 |

I have found a few online references that got close, but not exactly what I need:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html

https://trumpexcel.com/multiple-lookup-values-single-cell-excel/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have exactly what you need. Assuming your Color and Key table starts in A1 and "Red, Yellow" is in cell A8, try this formula in your Keys (joined) column: `=join(", ",arrayformula(vlookup(SPLIT(A8, ", "),$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)))`

This formula splits colors from a cell, does an individual vlookup for each color, then joins them together into an output for you.